Inequalities involving three positive real numbers
If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. Prove the inequality
$\displaystyle\frac{(a+b)}{2}\cdot\frac{(b+c)}{2}\cdot\frac{(c+a)}{2}\geqslant\frac{(a+b+c)}{3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$
I tried by using AM-GM inequality three times with
$\dfrac{(a+b)}{2}\geqslant\sqrt{ab}$ ,
$\dfrac{(b+c)}{2}\geqslant\sqrt{bc}$ and
$\dfrac{(c+a)}{2}\geqslant\sqrt{ca}$
Then I multiplied all three inequalities resulting in
$\dfrac{(a+b)}{2}\cdot\dfrac{(b+c)}{2}\cdot\dfrac{(c+a)}{2}\geqslant abc$
After this I got stuck.
We know that $\dfrac{(a+b+c)}{3}\geqslant\sqrt[3]{abc}$
So how to proceed after this ?
It’d be very helpful if someone gives a small hint.
Thank you in advance. Regards.

Shivam, you should learn to use MathJax in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

By AM-GM, $\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2} \le \frac{ab + bc + ca}{3}$.
